# Why isn't linking to a repository accepted?

Tags: discussion

Why is it not a standard in the Community to link to entire code repository when you ask a question, (not just have a question and the link, but have the link to reference the work your asking about) rather than update and edit continuously or periodically with bits and pieces of your code when someone who is willing to help you is asking for it? Are there any down sides to doing this? I see it being beneficial to people who really want to help a person out and the person needing the help themselves

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve <- minimal, complete, self-contained is what we aim for.

Comment: For context, sure. But just like pasty/codepad dumps, it can't substitute for fully working examples, or to hold out on crucial details. And it can't really become the common norm, since not every project is open source with a public repo.

Comment: And maybe this comes as a shock to you but we are not here to help you alone, your question and its answers are here for future visitors.

Comment: Your the man Rene thanks for clearing that up. I always look to you for answers and this is one of the times I needed your wit and knowledge thank you for serving and protecting

Answer (score 15):

> but why not have a standard in the Community to link to entire code repository when you ask a question

External code repositories can get stale. A SO question is supposed to be self-contained, it shouldn't require any external source to be complete.

But most importantly, linking to a repository doesn't really fit the format. Stack Overflow is a site for specific questions, not for tutoring or fixing other people's code repositories.

Isolating the bits of code that are *relevant to the question* is a healthy and necessary exercise for the asker.

> Are there any down sides to doing this because I am planning on doing
>   this for all future questions I ask here in the Stack community

That's likely to end in tears. Better stick to the convention in this case.

Comment: Good Call in retrospect that makes more sense, And wording  the question out in specifics is sometimes a great way to answer your own question yourself.